# Location Permission Status - always getting as denied in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, permissions, location, user-permissions

I have created below method to check the location permission status in my flutter application:

```
Future<void> checkLocationPermission(
  BuildContext context, UserCredential userCredential) async {
locationPermissionStatus = await permission_status.Permission.location
    .request()
    .then((value) async {
  if (locationPermissionStatus.isGranted) {
    displayToast("granted");
    await getCurrentLocation(context, userCredential);
  } else {
    displayToast("not granted");
  }
  return locationPermissionStatus;
});
 
}
```

Where, PermissionStatus is declared as below:

```
 permission_status.PermissionStatus locationPermissionStatus =
          permission_status.PermissionStatus.denied;
```

Imports as below:

```
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart' as permission_status;
```

Used below plugins:

```
permission_handler: ^10.2.0
location: ^4.4.0
```

But In App, When Location Permission pops up, I am tapping on option **"While Using the App"**

But I am always getting the toast display as **"not granted"**

What might be the issue? Thanks in Advance.

**EDIT:**
Already added below permissions for Android:

```
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.mypackage">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    </manifest>
```

Comment: Did  you added locatio permissions in manifest?

Comment: yes its added there in manifest dear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to the @Romil Mavani answer, you first have to add permissions in `AndroidManifest`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

But it also seems that you are using `async/await` with the combination of `then` which is very error-prone. You should either use one or the other.

```
Future<void> checkLocationPermission(
    BuildContext context, UserCredential userCredential) async {
  locationPermissionStatus =
      await permission_status.Permission.location.request();
  if (locationPermissionStatus.isGranted) {
    displayToast("granted");
    await getCurrentLocation(context, userCredential);
  } else {
    displayToast("not granted");
  }
}
```

Comment: By the way, Can you please reference me to check GPS On/Off status same way we have done with Permission? Thanks in Adavance.

Comment: I think that's possible with the geolocator package (https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) by listening to the `getServiceStatusStream` stream

Answer (score 1):

You have to add permission in manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgdNF.png

Also permission status is not working correctly for only location permission so you have check and request permission using location package and it will works fine.

**I Hope this things are solve your issue.**

Comment: Its there in Manifest dear!

Comment: use location package for locationPermissionStatus because PermissionStatus package is not working some time for Location permission.

Comment: Still getting denied! It might be issue of async await ??

Comment: yes i think so, have you tried with  async and await..?

Comment: ya done. Actually, I have used .then() with async and await, which was error prone. We can use either. then() or async & await.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a **Windows Emulator**

I've faced the same issue before, but when I opened the `application setting` of my mobile's emulator to confirm, the location permission was not granted (off).

So, I `granted it manually` from the app settings.

```
Emulator: Setting/apps/allApps/myApp/permisson
```

This solution works for me.